# Timestamp field is interpreted as String rather than date in kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

The timestamp field is interpreted as a string by elasticsearch when indexing document using the python elasticsearch client.
Elasticsearch version : 6.3.2
Kibana version : 6.3.2

I've also tried using `isotime()` with `time_obj`, pushing `time_obj` directly without converting it to any string and manually converting the `time_obj` to the valid date formats accepted by elasticsearch none of them works.

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
time_obj = timestamp

data = {
        "name" : random.choice(name_list),
        "env"  : random.choice(env_list), 

        #this is where problem lies
        "@timestamp" : time_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),

        "value" : random.randrange(min_value, max_value+1),
    }
es.index(index = 'sample', doc_type = 'gauge', body = data)
```

I just want that the timestamp field should be interpreted as a valid date format in kibana dashboard.

Comment: It has something to do in your mappings before you created your index. May you kindly edit your post and give us a screenshot of your index's mapping?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, was relying on elasticsearch before to automatically create the mapping.

Comment: hello @ad_03, did that do the trick? I mean you just fixed the "data type" for your field in your mappings? :)